# Radio button validation on javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, radio-button

im learning javascript, i got a radio button called gender, and its ID is male and female
i try to validate to check wether it's checked or not, but it doesnt return any error message even the radio button is not checked here's my code

```
 var maleC=document.getElementById('male').value;
 var femaleC=document.getElementById('female').value;

 if(maleC.checked==false||femaleC.checked==false)
{
    document.getElementById('err5').innerHTML="Gender must be choosen";
}
 else
  {
   alert("proceed");
   {
```

why it's doesnt work? can u help me guys?

Comment: When are you checking this? What event? What is not working?

Comment: I checked this when i press submit button, the event that not working is checked condition inside if...

Answer (score 3):

Should be

```
var maleC=document.getElementById('male');
var femaleC=document.getElementById('female');

 if(!(maleC.checked) || !(femaleC.checked))
{
    document.getElementById('err5').innerHTML="Gender must be choosen";
}
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

Comment: what's the different beetween

    var maleC=document.getElementById('male');

and

    var maleC=document.getElementById('male').value;

Comment: `maleC=document.getElementById('male').value;` it get the value of the radio input

Comment: `document.getElementById('male')` reference to the element by its ID

Answer (score 0):

may be

```
 if($("input[name=demo-radio]:checked").val()=="male")
{
}
else if($("input[name=demo-radio]:checked").val()=="female")
{
}

else{
alert("gender must be chosen");
}
```

for js:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked;
if(x==true){}
else{alert("please select a gender")}
```

Comment: It's in jquery, while OP wants to know in javascript

Answer (score 0):

While checking for checked property,use html element object, but here you are checking it on radio button value. Don't use `.value`

```
var maleC=document.getElementById('male'); // It will return you html element
 var femaleC=document.getElementById('female');

 if(!(maleC.checked)||!(femaleC.checked))
 {
    document.getElementById('err5').innerHTML="Gender must be choosen";
}
 else
  {
   alert("proceed");
   }
```